# Using OpenGL ES on the Mac

Tags: opengl-es, nsopenglview

Is it possible and not too complicated to use OpenGL ES for OS X development. I have been writing Mac applications for three years now and I am ready to start learning about OpenGL, but I want use OpenGL ES because there is a lot of information about using it with Xcode and Objective-C and from some of the code samples I found it seems easier to learn than the full OpenGL.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL-ES 1.1 is a true subset of OpenGL-2, ES-2 is a subset of OpenGL-3, the main difference is, how the context is created and managed. However context creation and management happen outside of OpenGL actually. So as long as you stick to OpenGL-ES, minus extensions specific to ES (i.e. OES extensions) you can do with an ordinary OpenGL context of the right version.

There are OpenGL-ES compatibility profiles, but those just disable functionality, don't add new one.